# IE 10 loses focus after logging in

Tags: cme, browser

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 development image, logging into Tridion set up for Windows Authentication moved IE to the background. I could get back to the CME by changing Windows.

IE details:

- Version: 10.0.9200.16635
- Update Version: 10.0.7

The behavior differs from Chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m or Firefox 22.0, which both keep focus after logging in.

**The "fix" was simply setting browser settings according to the documentation as described in the community answer below**, but I'd be interested in still keeping the pop-up without losing focus, so users can change their password in demos and training. Feel free to add other scenarios or details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting browser settings according to the [Configuring your Web browser for Content Manager Explorer](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) fixed this minor annoyance.

I suspect it's mainly having the site in the Local Intranet zone to let the Windows user authenticate automatically. Though other non-Tridion IE users have seen the browser lose focus after authentication [in this IE Microsoft Answers post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/ie-window-loses-focus/ae250782-362c-4f5e-a3d4-0a99a44aed5a).